# Avoid repeating costly method call for separate members Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

Can anyone please help me out to avoid this scenario,

```
CreateMap<Obj, ObjDTO>()
          .ForMember(d => d.Prop1, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => SomeMethod(src) == null ? null : SomeMethod(src).Prop1))
           .ForMember(d => d.Prop2, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => SomeMethod(src) == null? null : SomeMethod(src).Prop2));
```

Here `SomeMethod` needs to be called almost 4 times for 2 simple properties. It doesn't even support safe navigation operator.

Please share how you use to get rid of this scenario.

Comment: That most likely means that you write business code in your AM configuration and you should avoid that.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you could use an `AfterMap` action:

```
CreateMap<Obj, ObjDTO>()
    .ForMember(...)
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => 
    {
        var foo = SomeMethod(src);
        if (foo == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        dest.Prop1 = foo.Prop1;
        dest.Prop2 = foo.Prop2; 
    });
```

But the need for this is probably caused by you wanting to do too much in your mapping code. Ultimately, `src` should already be prepared to be mapped, having its `Prop1` and `Prop2` properties present and assigned.

Or you could use memoization in `SomeMethod()`, i.e. for each input you remember the output, and return the latter for repeated calls.